# CSS: Limit Element Width to Even Numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

I was wondering: I have a background image on a site I'm working on that needs to be very exactly positioned. Currently, its positioning is:

```
 body {
    ...
    width: 100%
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: -10px;
 }
```

This works pretty well -- for the most part the image stays centered in the x axis when a user resizes a window.

However, if the user resizes the window to an odd pixel width (ie body becomes 1001px not 1000px) then the background image seems to be positioned off by a bit (maybe 1 pixel?).

How can I fix this? Do I have to limit the element width to even numbers/how do I do this? Is there maybe a jQuery solution to this?

EDIT: A site named Simplegeo https://simplegeo.com/ manages to do this perfectly. Notice the tiled background: it's made with a repeated png file, and it's always perfectly positioned against the elements on the page. This shows it's possible.. but does anyone know how they did it?

Comment: There is no answer to this. The only way to fix this is change the resizing feature so that it always resizes in even pixels.

Comment: @Savage Garden: I added an edit showing a site that manages this. Any thoughts as to how?

Answer (score -1):

The way I see it, you got two options:

1) Resize the users window till to the closest even number (when a resize happens), something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hATKW/

2) Use a fixed width along with media queries to account for multiple sized windows, read on Media Queries here: http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score -1):

This website uses a background image which is 20x20 pix (even number). You may use

```
body {
min-width:400px;
}
```

At this width 1px off will be hardly be detectable and if the user re-sizes to larger window, the difference will be hardly noticeable.

I am not exactly sure about your question though. You are talking about *element* in the question, not the background. Would be helpful if you provide your site link.

Comment: hmm well.. for the sake of learning, let's just use this site as an example (mine is only on a local server). @simple geo when you resize the window slowly (pixel by pixel), you'll notice that the elements move half the time. This allows the background tile to continue to constitute the borders of the elements on the page. If this wasn't the case, being off by a pixel would mean that the resulting border would be off - which can be quite noticeable. Does what I am saying make sense?

Comment: the 1px difference is there as well. It just dont show up that big of a deal. You actual scenario matters since you want to keep the size of the *element* and not the background.